# How to run Python using Docker?

Tags: python, docker

I don't know Docker at all. I just use VS code or jupyter notebook to run notebook. I just bought a book and went to Github page of the authors trying to download the notebooks. It said I have to run docker. It is really annoying. I am wondering if I can download all these notebooks from the Docker using some sort of commands. Thanks

https://github.com/kylegallatin/ml-python-cookbook-runner

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/machine-learning-with/9781098135713/

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to just install docker on your system and run the command in that github readme. Why undo all that work?

Comment: Thanks. Just not familiar with Docker at all. not sure how to start. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, if you do want to do all this locally, check out the `DockerFile` it will show what steps are taking to build the image (think of it like a VM and this is the list of commands to run to make that VM). You'll see the `py` file and the `reqiurements.txt` file of all the modules to install. I, personally, wouldn't want to muddy up my environment without something like Conda to manage though.

Comment: Thanks, I just download Docker Desktop for windows, the started the Docker and I got an error of unexpected ESL error. It is quite annoying.